# Confusing LSMEANS results

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, glmm, lsmeans

I am having trouble interpreting results from a multiple comparison test.  Here is the model I ran:

```
m1 <-glmer(resp~Grp-1+offset(LArea)+(1|Crk/Meso)+(1|resid),data=df, family=binomial)
```

And here are the results from the lsmeans function:

```
> lsmeans(m1, pairwise ~ Grp, adjustSigma = TRUE, adjust = "sidak")
$lsmeans
 Grp      lsmean        SE df asymp.LCL  asymp.UCL
 90U   -0.207353 0.6345219 NA -1.450993  1.0362871
 90I   -2.214079 0.7946987 NA -3.771660 -0.6564978
 96U   -1.605763 0.6551178 NA -2.889770 -0.3217555
 96I   -3.168827 0.7957100 NA -4.728390 -1.6092644
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

OK, everything is great so far.  I can see that the lsmean order is `90U>96U>90I>96I`.  So now I want to check the observed differences are significant:

```
> cld(lsmeans(m1, pairwise ~ Grp, adjustSigma =TRUE, adjust = "sidak"))
 Grp      lsmean        SE df asymp.LCL  asymp.UCL .group
 96I   -3.168827 0.7957100 NA -4.728390 -1.6092644  1    
 90I   -2.214079 0.7946987 NA -3.771660 -0.6564978  12   
 96U   -1.605763 0.6551178 NA -2.889770 -0.3217555  1    
 90U   -0.207353 0.6345219 NA -1.450993  1.0362871   2   

Confidence level used: 0.95 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05
```

But now I am confused.  How can `90I` be grouped with `90U` while excluding `96U`?  It is saying `-2.2 = -0.2` while `-2.2!=-1.6` and `-1.6 != -0.2`  If it helps, here is an image with the 95%CI:
[Plot of estimated coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsTvV.png)

The explanations I have thought of but find unconvincing are:

- lsmean ignores the random effects, effectively running a plain-jane pairwise comparison.
- This is a perfectly reasonable conclusion.

My running hypothesis:

- I_have_no_idea_what_I_am_doing.jpg

And a brief aside: Why does it perform a Tukey adjustment when I ask for a Sidak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer -- statistical [non]significance is *not* transitive.

It will help you if you look at confidence intervals for the differences. The following will show what's going on with the default tukey-adjusted results:

```
confint(pairs(lsmeans(m1, "Grp")))
```

You will find that some comparisons have wider CIs than others. The reason Tukey overrode your Sidak is that your `lsmeans` call asks for both LSmeans and pairwise comparisons thereof -- two different sets of linear functions. If you put the `adjust` spec in the `cld` call instead of the `lsmeans` call, it'll do the right thing.

Comment: Ahh, it just clicked.  I read your comment and thought "yeah I get that but there is no possible structure of CIs that would skip an estimate between the two extremes..."  Then I realized my mistake.  I was interpreting the two "groups" (1 and 2) given by cld independently.  Group 2 only makes sense if you also consider group 1 at the same time.  Thanks!